# React Redux Unique key prop

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to use redux to my react app, but i am getting stuck in rendering the data to my component.

When i console log my this.props.expositions, it get in fact call 2 time the first time is an empty array and the second time is the same array with all expected data.

[image]
Then here is my code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import './exposition.css';
// import ExpoResult from './expo.result';
import { getExposition } from '../../redux.reducer/exposition/actions';

  

class Exposition extends React.Component {

  render()  {

console.log(this.props.expositions); 
    return (
      <div className="Exposition"> 
         <h1 className="uk-text-center">Expositions</h1>
         <ul>
             
              { 
               
                  this.props.expositions.length !== '' && this.props.expositions.map( (x, index) => { 
                    <li key={index}>
                      {x.name}
                    </li>
                  )
          }
         </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    expositions: state.exposition
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Exposition);
```

Comment: Do you still get the error if you add the index argument to your . map callback and use it as the key? Just wondering if it could be something to do with the initial state of props, _maybe_ `x.name` isn't unique?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This could be because `this.props.expositions` has duplicate names, you can change `this.props.expositions.map(x =>` to `this.props.expositions.map( (x, index) => ` and `<li key={x.name}>` to `<li key={index}>` At the same time you can also change `this.props.expositions.map( (x, index) => ` to `this.props.expositions.length > 0 && this.props.expositions.map( (x, index) => ` so its only executes if the length of array is greater than 0

Comment: (x, index), solved the key problem, but i still does not have any output on screen and still return 2 time console.log() first is empty array and second with all data

Comment: It's called twice because the component is rendered two times, What's the structure of your Array items?

Comment: I try your suggestion, you can see above i edited the question.  I don't know how to control if the component is render 1 or 2  times and how to know it

Comment: Instead if `this.props.expositions.length !== '' && this.props.expositions.map( (x, index) => {` do `this.props.expositions && this.props.expositions.length > 0 && this.props.expositions.map( (x, index) => {` Also don't worry about the component being rendered multiple times, This will happen everytime the state changes and if you're listening for that state change. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You should re-format the code below and/or change the structure of your data.

The array items are not rendered because you're not returning it.
Change your code for **`expositions.map`** to this

```
<ul>
{
    this.props.expositions.length > 0 && this.props.expositions[0].length > 0 && this.props.expositions[0].map( (x, index) => { 
        return(
            <li key={index}>
                {x.name}
            </li>
        )
    )
}
</ul>
```

And if you want you can do something like this to show the data if it exists or something else if it doesn't exist.

```
<div>
{ this.props.expositions[0].length > 0 ?
    (
    <div>
        <h2>Here's the array data.</h2>
        <ul>
        { this.props.expositions[0].map( (x, index) => { 
            return(
                <li key={index}>
                    {x.name}
                </li>
            )
        ) }
        </ul>
    </div>
    ) :
    (
    <div>
        <p>The content is empty.. or we're loading data please wait.</p>
    </div>
    )
}
</div>
```

Comment: Your first answer give me an empty <li> ( the first point of <li> ) is render on the pages. Do you think it may has something to do with (reducer, actions, store) ?

Comment: Oh F, I just saw you're array is returning another array.. updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `state.exposition` or `this.props.expositions` was empty at first run, `x.name` is probably `null` or `undefined` or just an empty string, which makes your `key` non-unique over different `li`s. That's why you are getting the error if that is your question.

As for why `console.log(this.props.exposition)` being called twice, it is because your component is rendered twice. It means your initial state of `state.exposition` is an empty array, and for the second time, it is being set a bit later elsewhere. This may be because you are calling asynchronous code somewhere else to set `state.exposition`.

The solution can be: Do not render the component at all, that is, early `return` in the `render` method if the `this.props.expositions` is empty.

```
render()  {
  if (!this.props.expositions || 
         this.props.expositions.length === 0) return null;    // Early return

  return (
    <div className="Exposition"> 
       <h1 className="uk-text-center">Expositions</h1>
       <ul>  
        {   
            this.props.expositions.map(x => 
              <li key={x.name}>
                {x.name}
              </li>
            );
        }
       </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Exposition.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: Thanks for catching that out!